# How to stack and rename N successive columns in df

Tags: pandas

How would I achieve the **desired output** as shown below? Ie, stack the **first** 3 columns underneath each other, stack the **second** 3 columns underneath each other and rename the columns.

```
d = {'A': [76, 34], 'B': [21, 48], 'C': [45, 89], 'D': [56, 41], 'E': [3, 2],
     'F': [78, 32]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Output

```
df
    A   A   A   A  A   A
0  76  21  45  56  3  78
1  34  48  89  41  2  32
```

**Desired Output**

```
   Z1  Z2
0  76  56
1  34  41
2  21  3
3  48  2
4  45  78
5  89  32
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go down into numpy, reshape and create a new dataframe:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape((-1, 2), order='F'), columns = ['Z1','Z2'])
Out[19]: 
   Z1  Z2
0  76  56
1  34  41
2  21   3
3  48   2
4  45  78
5  89  32
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how the `reshape((-1,2), order='F')` section works ?

Comment: (-1,2) is a `(row, col)` format and implies create a 2 column array, the -1 is a shortcut to creating the required rows, since we have specified the number of columns needed